# two sum python solution

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    for i in nums:
        j=target-i 
        if ((j in nums)==True and (nums.index(j) != nums.index(i))):
            return [nums.index(i), nums.index(j)]
```

it passed the case for list [2,7,11,15] but not [3,3]. I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: nums.index gives you the first index in the array. So even if the number exists twice, you won't be able to use it. You should instead build a dictionary of number => indices and iterate over that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it supposes to return the indices of the two value in nums that will add up to the target in the form [i,j]

Comment: @fafl I see. So it only finds the first occurance of that value.. sad. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works and can do it in a single pass:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Returns the indices of two numbers that add up to the target
def two_sums(nums, target):

    lookup = defaultdict(list)
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        needed = target - num
        if needed in lookup:
            return [lookup[needed][0], i]
        lookup[num].append(i)

    return None

print(two_sums([2,7,11,15], 17))
print(two_sums([3, 3], 6))
```

Comment: This is a great solution using defaultdict to avoid key error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't even need to save a list of indices, the last one would be totally enough

Answer (score 12):

I found 3 main ways to solve this question, the 1st approach is brute force with time complexity of O(n^2) and space complexity of O(1):

```
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
            if array[i] + array[j] == targetSum:
                return ([array[i], array[j]])
    return []
```

The 2nd approach is using hash map with time complexity of O(n) and space complexity of O(n):

```
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    matches = {}
    for number in array:
        match = targetSum - number
        if match in matches:
            return [match, number]
        else:
            matches[number] = True
    return []
```

The 3rd approach is with two pointers of left and right. This method has time complexity of O(nlogn) and space complexity of O(1):

```
def twoNumberSum(array, targetSum):
    array.sort()
    left = 0
    right = len(array) - 1
    while left < right:
        if array[left] + array[right] == targetSum:
            return [array[left], array[right]]
        elif array[left] + array[right] < targetSum:
            left +=1
        elif array[left] + array[right] > targetSum:
            right -=1
    return []
```

Comment: The way the problem is most often phrased requires you to return the indices of the array, not the elements. All of these solutions could be modified to do that with O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity, using array.index(i), or O(1) time complexity and O(n) space complexity by first converting the array into a hashmap/dictionary and looking up the index of an element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be:

```
def two_sum(nums, target):
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        x = nums[i]
        if target - x in dict:
            return (d[target - x] + 1, i + 1)
        d[x] = i
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 98.8 percent better way from other leetcode answers

```
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        required = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if target - nums[i] in required:
                return [required[target - nums[i]],i]
            else:
                required[nums[i]]=i
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution;
I found the solution by checking if it is in this series with a for loop (target-n) in the series.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        for n in nums:
            if (target - n) in nums:
                return [nums.index(n), nums.index(target - n)]
            return "Unfortunately there is no twoSum for your target variable!"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).